# Writing Bytes on USB Device

Tags: python, linux, bash, usb

I have a USB-Device that I would like to send some bytes to.

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04b4:0a0a Cypress Semiconductor Corp.
```

With Wireshark and usbmon, I figured, that a certain byte sequence leads to the desired behaviour(it unlocks a physical lock).
Now I would like to copy this and send it myself. Therefore I tried to create a binary file and write it on the bus like this:

```
cat byteFile > /dev/bus/usb/001/005
```

But I get the following error:

```
cat: write error: Invalid argument
```

Now it seems that it is not possible to write bytes on "raw" USB-Devices, but I did not find the correct(or generic) approach to do this. How can I send the byte sequence from the file to the USB-Device? I would be happy to get this running in python/java or bash if possible. Such that I can later use it in my program. -> No GUI-application ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send raw bytes to a USB device. Intead you send URB (that is USB Request Blocks) to a USB endpoint.

With usbmon you can discover that endpoint and what are the parameters and payload of the URB, and then replicate that from your program by using `libusb`.

But `libusb` is a C library to access raw USB devices, but I am not aware of any way to use it directly from the command line. My advice is to write a simple C program that sends the data you want to the proper endpoint and just call it from your script.

Comment: @Salocin: I'm not familiar with PyUSB, but it looks like a `libusb` wrapper or reimplementation in Python, so I think it should work.

Comment: it did work.. I just copied the URB setup part of wireshark and reused them as arguments.. the locks open and close :)
thank you!

Comment: For anyone to find more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943825/pyusb-send-hid-report