# Q: Write a string to HID device in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, hid, raspberry-pi4, evdev

I have an RFID reader with 2 antennas (ant1, ant2) attached to a RPi4 (raspbian) that behaves as a HID USB keyboard. I have managed to read its antennas oputput following these posts:

1. [How can I get a String from HID device in Python with evdev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732978/how-can-i-get-a-string-from-hid-device-in-python-with-evdev)
2. [Send HID report with PyUSB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943825/send-hid-report-with-pyusb)
3. [USB HID device only firing 1 event](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/usb-hid-device-only-firing-1-event)

The code in Python3 for continuously reading the antennas using the `evdev` module is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This script reads the output from HID device rfid scanner
# Make sure evdev is installed or install it with: pip3 install evdev.
# The Kernel on the Pi creates an input device which resides in /dev/input/.
# You can find out the names and other attributes of different devices using:
# cat /proc/bus/input/devices

import sys
import inspect
import serial
import time
import random
import csv

import evdev
from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes as e, list_devices

device = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event1')     # check the event id first with cat 

# reserve the device or maybe not
device.grab()

# return the current line number
def lineno():
    return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno

CODE_MAP_CHAR = {
    'KEY_MINUS': "-",
    'KEY_SPACE': " ",    
    'KEY_U': "U",
    'KEY_W': "W",
    'KEY_BACKSLASH': "\\",
    'KEY_GRAVE': "`",
    'KEY_NUMERIC_STAR': "*",
    'KEY_NUMERIC_3': "3",
    'KEY_NUMERIC_2': "2",
    'KEY_NUMERIC_5': "5",
    'KEY_NUMERIC_4': "4",
    'KEY_NUMERIC_7': "7",
    'KEY_NUMERIC_6': "6",
    'KEY_NUMERIC_9': "9",
    'KEY_NUMERIC_8': "8",
    'KEY_NUMERIC_1': "1",
    'KEY_NUMERIC_0': "0",
    'KEY_E': "E",
    'KEY_D': "D",
    'KEY_G': "G",
    'KEY_F': "F",
    'KEY_A': "A",
    'KEY_C': "C",
    'KEY_B': "B",
    'KEY_M': "M",
    'KEY_L': "L",
    'KEY_O': "O",
    'KEY_N': "N",
    'KEY_I': "I",
    'KEY_H': "H",
    'KEY_K': "K",
    'KEY_J': "J",
    'KEY_Q': "Q",
    'KEY_P': "P",
    'KEY_S': "S",
    'KEY_X': "X",
    'KEY_Z': "Z",
    'KEY_q': "q",
    'KEY_w': "w",
    'KEY_e': "e",
    'KEY_r': "r",
    'KEY_t': "t",
    'KEY_z': "z",
    'KEY_u': "u",
    'KEY_i': "i",
    'KEY_o': "o",
    'KEY_p': "p",
    'KEY_a': "a",
    'KEY_s': "s",
    'KEY_d': "d",
    'KEY_f': "f",
    'KEY_g': "g",
    'KEY_h': "h",
    'KEY_j': "k",
    'KEY_l': "l",
    'KEY_y': "y",
    'KEY_x': "x",
    'KEY_c': "c",
    'KEY_v': "v",
    'KEY_b': "b",
    'KEY_n': "n",
    'KEY_m': "m",
    'KEY_KP4': "4",
    'KEY_KP5': "5",
    'KEY_KP6': "6",
    'KEY_KP7': "7",
    'KEY_KP0': "0",
    'KEY_KP1': "1",
    'KEY_KP2': "2",
    'KEY_KP3': "3",
    'KEY_KP8': "8",
    'KEY_KP9': "9",
    'KEY_5': "5",
    'KEY_4': "4",
    'KEY_7': "7",
    'KEY_6': "6",
    'KEY_1': "1",
    'KEY_0': "0",
    'KEY_3': "3",
    'KEY_2': "2",
    'KEY_9': "9",
    'KEY_8': "8",
    'KEY_LEFTBRACE': "[",
    'KEY_RIGHTBRACE': "]",    
    'KEY_COMMA': ",",
    'KEY_EQUAL': "=",    
    'KEY_SEMICOLON': ";",
    'KEY_APOSTROPHE': "'",
    'KEY_T': "T",
    'KEY_V': "V",
    'KEY_R': "R",
    'KEY_Y': "Y",
    'KEY_TAB': "\t",
    'KEY_DOT': ".",
    'KEY_SLASH': "/",
}

scancodes = {
    # Scancode: ASCIICode
    0: None, 1: u'ESC', 2: u'1', 3: u'2', 4: u'3', 5: u'4', 6: u'5', 7: u'6', 8: u'7', 9: u'8',
    10: u'9', 11: u'0', 12: u'-', 13: u'=', 14: u'BKSP', 15: u'TAB', 16: u'Q', 17: u'W', 18: u'E', 19: u'R',
    20: u'T', 21: u'Y', 22: u'U', 23: u'I', 24: u'O', 25: u'P', 26: u'[', 27: u']', 28: u'CRLF', 29: u'LCTRL',
    30: u'A', 31: u'S', 32: u'D', 33: u'F', 34: u'G', 35: u'H', 36: u'J', 37: u'K', 38: u'L', 39: u';',
    40: u'"', 41: u'`', 42: u'LSHFT', 43: u'\\', 44: u'Z', 45: u'X', 46: u'C', 47: u'V', 48: u'B', 49: u'N',
    50: u'M', 51: u',', 52: u'.', 53: u'/', 54: u'RSHFT', 56: u'LALT', 100: u'RALT'
}

def parse_key_to_char(val):
    return CODE_MAP_CHAR[val] if val in CODE_MAP_CHAR else ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
        
    event_id = 1    # set event id for lcd
    exclusive_access = 1    # grant exclusive access

    device = InputDevice('/dev/input/event{}'.format(event_id))
    if int(exclusive_access) == 1:
        device.grab()
        
    obidList = []   # set list for the reply string
    #print(lineno(), "obidList:", obidList)
    
    #get reply
    for event in device.read_loop():
        if event.type == evdev.ecodes.EV_KEY:
            e = categorize(event)
            if e.keystate == e.key_up:
                sys.stdout.write(parse_key_to_char(e.keycode))
                cifra = parse_key_to_char(e.keycode)
                obidList.append(cifra)
                print(lineno(), obidList)
                sys.stdout.flush()
            if e.scancode == 28:
                obidString = "".join(obidList)  # convert the list into a string
                obidString = obidString.strip() # strip of eventual white spaces
                print(lineno(), obidString)
                break
```

The output of the code above is:

```
(py3) pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/Python3 $ python obid_read.py 
device /dev/input/event1, name "FEIG ELECTRONIC GmbH OBID RFID-Reader", phys "usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3/input1" 

10004597E7A656780,02204 bag, antenna2: 004597E7A656780,02
208 obidCount: 1
0004597E7A656780,020004597E7A656780,01197 cartridge, antenna1: 004597E7A656780,020004597E7A656780,020004597E7A656780,01
201 obidCount: 2
004597E7A656780,(py3) pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/Python3 $ 004597E7A656780,02
```

To gain control over the reader and being able to read a single antenna, I have to send a string to the device. The string is in hex and needs to be converted to byte fist:

```
# strings to send
hex_string_ant1 = "02 00 0A FF B0 01 10 01 EF 14"
hex_string_ant2 = "02 00 0A FF B0 01 10 02 74 26"
byte_string_1 = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string_ant1)
byte_string_2 = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string_ant2)
```

I have checked the `evdev` documentation that covers [injecting input keys pressing](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#injecting-input) but can not see how to relate. How can I send a byte string to the device with evedev?