# Pyusb doesn't recognize usb devices (python 3.9.6 and windows)

Tags: python, pyusb

I'm trying to use pyusb to enumerates all devices connected to my pc:

```
>>> import usb.core
>>> dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
>>> for device in dev:
        print(device)

    
>>>
```

Why keyboard, mouse and other plugged devices are not recognized?

Then I try to detect the mouse:

```
>>> dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=16700, idProduct=12314)
>>> print(dev)
None
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!
Max

Comment: I would bet on windows permissions, try to start the python as administrator

Comment: Same result, it doesn't recognize any usb device...

Comment: I tried exact same code on Macbook, python 3.7.5... worked on first try, even tho I have usb-c only.
Fortunetly I found that windows needs to install libusb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773132/pyusb-on-windows-no-backend-available

Comment: Honestly, I did not understand very well that discussion, as far as I know the dll are present in my system but it still doesn't work. When I try to detect the mouse: >>> dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=16700, idProduct=12314)
>>> print(dev)
None

Comment: Is this on Windows?  On Windows, HID devices already have drivers, and cannot be attached to another device without disconnecting the original driver..

Comment: Yes is on Windows, does it means I can't interact with HID devices (keyboard, mouse...) by using Pyusb?

Comment: I used pyusb after tried unsuccessfully with Hid and Hidapi...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68302491/python-and-hidapi-argument-error-when-trying-to-write-a-usb-device